# Rename [python-xray] -> [xarray]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We recently renamed this project from "xray" (which has a number of conflicts in other programming languages outside Python), to "xarray". It would be great to update the Stack Overflow tag as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-xray/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behold: [python-xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-xarray). (python-xray is a synonym, so anything tagged with that now will get remapped to the new tag.)