# Rename [python-xarray] -> [xarray]?

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

There are now two tags that are widely used for the xarray Python project, [python-xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-xarray/) (203 uses, past 2 years) and [xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xarray/) (44 uses, past 11 months). It would be nice to consolidate these.

I think users find the tag "python-xarray" confusing or at have difficulty finding it because none of the other related Python projects (e.g., scipy, numpy, pandas) use the "python" prefix.

My request:

- Is it possible to now switch both `python-xray` and `python-xarray` to remap to `xarray` now? I couldn't figure out how to do this on the "suggest tag synonyms" page.
- If it's not possible to remap such an already redirected tag, then I suppose remapping `xarray` -> `python-xarray` would be the next best choice (but I do still think users will find this confusing).

**Full backstory**: the project was originally called "xray" and we got [help to rename the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315460/rename-python-xray-xarray) two years ago. I did request `xarray` but I guess the moderator picked the more conservative `python-xarray` based on similarity to the previous tag (`xray` needed the `python-` prefix because there many open source projects that use the same name).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> I think users find the tag "python-xarray" confusing or at **have difficulty finding** it because none of the other related Python projects (e.g., scipy, numpy, pandas) use the "python" prefix.

This is irrelevant.

> [image]

As it can be seen, partial matches are shown for anyone that types enough. Typing less than "xarra" won't even show you the xarray tag, but typing "xar" already shows you python-xarray. Also, if it was so difficult to find, then why would the python- tag have more than the unprefixed one.

Comment: My guess is that many users may not even look at auto-complete? Honestly I'm not sure. `python-xarray` has been around longer (including everything originally tagged `python-xray`) and we also link to it from our project's documentation as the preferred support channel. So it's not surprising that it's used more, it's surprising that the other tag is used at all.

Comment: Sounds like `xarray` should be a synonym for `python-xarray` then